# App is not able to restore from backup on iPhone

Tags: ios, backup, restore

I have installed a debug-app into my iPhone device and did backup.

However the backup app does not show on iPhone once I wipe device and restore from iTune.

Does backup/restore only support app installed from Apple store?

Thanks,
Jef

Answer (score 0):

To save time and space, Apps aren't actually backed up, only their data is.  When you restore from back up, apps are simply re-installed from the App Store.  As a result, apps that aren't in the App Store (such as apps you are developing yourself) aren't restored.  You will need to re-install them using Xcode.